# C++14: Calling a static constexpr template method of template class in `std::enable_if

Tags: c++, c++14

I have the following minimal example:

```
template <class TLeafType, std::size_t TN>
class cls {
    using LeafType = TLeafType;

    template<typename T>
    static constexpr bool HasNumLeaf() {return std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, double>::value;}

    public:
    template<typename Q = TLeafType>
    typename std::enable_if<HasNumLeaf<Q>(), std::size_t>::type my_impl();

    template<typename Q = TLeafType>
    typename std::enable_if<!HasNumLeaf<Q>(), std::size_t>::type my_impl();
};

template <class TLeafType, std::size_t TN>
template<typename Q>
typename std::enable_if<cls<TLeafType, TN>::template HasNumLeaf<Q>(), std::size_t>::type cls<TLeafType, TN>::my_impl()
{
    std::cout << "Is numeric!!!!" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

template <class TLeafType, std::size_t TN>
template<typename Q>
typename std::enable_if<!cls<TLeafType, TN>::template HasNumLeaf<Q>(), std::size_t>::type cls<TLeafType, TN>::my_impl()
{
    std::cout << "Is not numeric!!!!" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    cls<std::string, 10> a;
    cls<double, 12> b;

    std::cout << std::endl<< std::endl << "a: " << std::endl;
    a.my_impl();

    std::cout << std::endl<< std::endl << "b: " << std::endl;
    b.my_impl();
}
```

In this example, I wanted to call the static constexpr template method `HasNumLeaf()` in the context of the first `std::enable_if<>` template in order to enable or disable the corresponding class methods `my_impl()`.

i.e. the problem is the following part: `std::enable_if<cls<TLeafType, TN>::template HasNumLeaf<Q>(), std::size_t>`

When i'm compiling with g++, I get the following error:

```
error: no declaration matches ‘typename std::enable_if<HasNumLeaf<Q>(), long unsigned int>::type cls<TLeafType, TN>::my_impl()’
 typename std::enable_if<cls<TLeafType, TN>::template HasNumLeaf<Q>(), std::size_t>::type cls<TLeafType, TN>::my_impl()
note: candidates are: ‘template<class TLeafType, long unsigned int TN> template<class Q> typename std::enable_if<(! HasNumLeaf<Q>()), long unsigned int>::type cls<TLeafType, TN>::my_impl()’
 if<!HasNumLeaf<Q>(), std::size_t>::type my_impl();
note:                 ‘template<class TLeafType, long unsigned int TN> template<class Q> typename std::enable_if<HasNumLeaf<Q>(), long unsigned int>::type cls<TLeafType, TN>::my_impl()’
 _if<HasNumLeaf<Q>(), std::size_t>::type my_impl();
...
```

With clang++, I get the following error:

```
error: out-of-line definition of 'my_impl' does not match any declaration in 'cls<TLeafType, TN>'
typename std::enable_if<cls<TLeafType, TN>::template HasNumLeaf<Q>(), std::size_t>::type cls<TLeafType, TN>::my_impl()
```

But if I declare the methods inline, everything compiles:

```
template <class TLeafType, std::size_t TN>
class cls {
    using LeafType = TLeafType;

    template<typename T>
    static constexpr bool HasNumLeaf() {return std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, double>::value;}

    public:
    template<typename Q = TLeafType>
    typename std::enable_if<HasNumLeaf<Q>(), std::size_t>::type my_impl()
    {
        std::cout << "Is numeric!!!!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    template<typename Q = TLeafType>
    typename std::enable_if<!HasNumLeaf<Q>(), std::size_t>::type my_impl()
    {
        std::cout << "Is not numeric!!!!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
};
```

What am I doing wrong in the case of external defined methods?